# Crystal Reports: Text field flow justified around image/margin indentation

Tags: text, layout, crystal-reports

I'm creating a report that outputs a letter. The first page contains is a large left margin containing static company information. The letter output can be multiple pages, however I only want the text on the first page indented to the right away from the left margin. How can I accomplish this with one text field (the letter body is all one data field)?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6SGr.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your text field and select 'Size & Position'. Here you can set the X and Y positions of the field, and the X value can be set conditionally. All you have to do is something like:

`if pagenumber=1 then 0 else 1440`

Watch out, though, the units used in the formula are twips, not the units listed as your default in the Size & Position window. FYI, 1440 twips to an inch or 20 twips to a point.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the better solution -- that's what I get for trying to answer the question from memory.

Comment: When you say right click, I assume you mean on the object inside the report editor? I do not have a Size & Position option, it only has "Edit Text Object" and "Format Object" (and then move/cut/copy/paste). If I look at it's properties, I do see the Left property, but it requires numerical input.

Comment: Also, I'm using the Crystal Reports that comes with Visual Studio 2008. What version are you using that has this option?

Comment: @Maverick: Yes, I mean right-click on the text field. I'm using CR 2008, but I know that the conditional x-position goes back at least to CR XI. I don't use Visual Studio so I'm not entirely sure about the version discrepancies there. Can you post a screen of what you're seeing when you right-click?

Comment: @Ryan Here's what I see right clicking http://i.imgur.com/lCYtV.png and if I select Format Object http://imgur.com/qrnGW.png

Comment: In Visual Studio, isn't the x-position just an object property (meaning you can set it conditionally the same way I described above)? Again, I've never used Visual Studio so this is just a guess. If not, you can always go with LittleBobbyTables answer and create two text boxes and selectively suppress them.

Comment: Yes, "Left" (or x-position) is an object property, but it does not allow any input other than numerical. I'll have to check out the 2008 version you are using, if I have to convert the project to get the feature, I guess I will do that.